# android airpush integration showing airpush can not resolved to a type

Tags: android, airpush

i was integrated airpush to my app and almost i have done all the types of ads like Banner ad, smart wall, full screen , dialog ad, etc with new Airpush sdk but at the end i was stuck up with push notifications type. Here am getting error like this.

```
Airpush airpush;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    airpush=new Airpush(getApplicationContext(), null);
    airpush.startPushNotification(false); 

}
```

eclipse showing airpush cannot resolved to a type. and i have gone through google and stack over flow and found plenty of questions and i have applied applied the solutions that were provided earlier. But this error still there. I was added new Airpush sdk to libs and
couple of times i clean and build the project.
any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using very old Airpush SDK, Now a days Airpush is serving it's SDK in many flavours with respect revenue,PPD & Google Ad compliance. 
To know more details about latest SDK's and Docs please prefer this link : http://manage.airpush.com/publishers/publishers/downloadsdk/